# Ignorar elementos de una lista de tuplas

Tags: haskell

Tengo una lista de `String`

`[A,B]`

Y tengo esta tupla

```
[("A","B"),("A","C"),("B","A"),("B","C"),("C","A"),("C","B"),("C","D"),("D","C")]
```

Quiero eliminar los elementos de la lista a partir de la lista `[A,B]` es decir obtener el siguiente resultado

> `[("C","D"),("D","C")]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si entiendo bien, quieres *filtrar* la lista de tuplas para que no tenga elementos de otra lista. Una solución sería usar comprensión de listas:

```
[(x,y) | (x,y) <- lista, x `notElem` ["A","B"], y `notElem` ["A","B"]]
```